# .HTACCESS prioritizing code. It ignores everything after first rule

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Why I can't keep all these lines in my .HTACCESS ?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ user.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ user.php?id=$1

// this code below wont work, But if remove the upper code, 
//It works fine. What could be the reason ?

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

It seems to me that it is somehow prioritizing the first lines and ignoring the later ones. What to do ? 
  In first one, I'm cleaning the URL
  In second - Trying to hide extension.
  Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're matching pretty much everything using pattern `[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+` in first rule that's why that rule overrides 2nd rule. It is better to move 2nd rule before 1st rule and check if corresponding `.php` file exists before adding `.php` extension.

Try these rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

# To internally forward /dir/file to /dir/file.php
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule . %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]

# your first rule    
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ user.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

- `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}\.php` expression is used to build full path to `.php` file
- `-f` is used to check if `.php` file exists
- `\w` is same as `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`
- `QSA` (Query String Append) flag preserves existing query parameters while adding a new one.

Comment: Can you be a little more elaborative, Please ? I'm unable to grasp.

Comment: It doesn't. BTW, I didn't understand the comment.

Comment: Not Found

The requested URL /project/page.php.php was not found on this server.

Comment: It worked ! Finally ! Thanks a lot. Do you mind giving me a little explanation ?

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite rules are evaluated first. If the pattern is true, then the condition will be checked. If you remove the first two rewrite rules, then the last rewrite rule is evaluating to true and the condition gets checked.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do this with the `RewriteEngine On` and `[L, QSA]`.

QSA appends the query string to the end. L means, 'don't process any more rules after this'. 
The second `RewriteEngine On` turns it back on.

I'm probably terribly misinformed about this but...it should work.
Good job on deciding to do SEO optimization for your user links, however!

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ user.php?id=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ user.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]


RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Thanks, Austin. I tried your code But same problem persists. I do get a cleaner URL But not with the later problem of hiding URLs.